# Using records as function arguments in SML

Tags: sml

The one subject in SML which does not get much attention is 'records'.

I was wondering how to handle records in functions (as an argument or returented value). I know we can use the `#` operator in order to get an element of the record.  But How should I pass the record to the function? is there a special pattern matching for that?

I have tried:

```
fun foo r = #1 r;
```

It ends with the following error:

```
Error: unresolved flex record
(can't tell what fields there are besides #1)
```

I didn't find any guide online which explains this part of records, in SML.

Also I tried:

```
fun foo {1=2,2=3} = 5;
```

And found out that tuples are actually syntax-sugar of records. Of Course I got the `match` warning, but at least it worked this time. The real question is how to handle 'generic' records. Could be helpful to see some examples or a reference to a guide on the subject.

It will be more then helpful to see also explanation about the signatures of those functions (as I mentioned records like `{1=2,2=3}` will get different signatures then `{a=2,b=3}`).

Comment: I suspect that what you mean with "generic" records is [row polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_polymorphism), which Standard ML does not have.

Answer (score 3):

> The one subject in SML which does not get much attention is 'records'.

I'm not sure what you mean. Standard textbooks on SML usually cover this. For example, [ML for the Working Programmer, 2nd Ed.](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html) chapter 2, *Names, Functions and Types*, pp. 28 and on covers them. This book is free as a PDF, so you can read this chapter if you like.

If you read chapter 2, p. 34 it covers *record patterns*:

```
- val richardIII =
      { name = "Richard III"
      , born = 1452
      , crowned = 1483
      , died = 1485
      , quote = "Plots have I laid..."
      };

> val richardIII =
      {born = 1452, crowned = 1483, died = 1485, name = "Richard III",
       quote = "Plots have I laid..."} :
  {born : int, crowned : int, died : int, name : string, quote : string}

- val { name = richard_name, died = richard_died, ... } = richardIII;
> val richard_name = "Richard III" : string
  val richard_died = 1485 : int
```

These record patterns are also possible in function arguments.

I recommend that you read a textbook on SML on this and other subjects.

StackOverflow is a poor format for reproducing one.

> The real question is how to handle 'generic' records

Depending on what you mean by *generic* records, SML may not be able to do that.

For example, you can define the function

```
- fun f { x, y } = x + y;
> val f = fn : {x : int, y : int} -> int
```

But if you try to define one that extracts `x` and `y` from an arbitrary record without specifying the remaining record type,

```
- fun f { x, y, ... } = x + y;
! Toplevel input:
! fun f { x, y, ... } = x + y;
!       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
! Unresolved record pattern
```

Whereas if you specified the type of record,

```
- fun f ({ x, y, ... } : { x : int, y : int, z : int }) = x + y;
> val f = fn : {x : int, y : int, z : int} -> int
```

or equivalently via a type alias,

```
- type coord = { x : int, y : int, z : int };
> type coord = {x : int, y : int, z : int}
- fun f ({ x, y, ... } : coord) = x + y;
> val f = fn : {x : int, y : int, z : int} -> int
```

then that works as fine as using `#x` and `#y`:

```
- fun f (coord : coord) = #x coord + #y coord;
> val f = fn : {x : int, y : int, z : int} -> int
```

and without any kind of type annotation or inference, this will also fail to recognize the particular record type:

```
- fun f coord = #x coord + #y coord;
! Toplevel input:
! fun f coord = #x coord + #y coord;
!               ^^
! Unresolved record pattern
```

So SML does not handle *generic* records in this sense even though it's technically possible to allow for this in a language. Perhaps this was not the meaning you went for. Perhaps record patterns were what you needed. I'll let you dig into the textbook material and resolve this.

**Updated:** As Andreas Rossberg suggested, I've simplified the examples a little.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the type annotations on the record *fields* are entirely optional: `fun f {x = x, y = y} = x + y` works just fine. Moreover, this can be abbreviated to `fun f {x, y} = x + y` for further convenience.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg: Thanks, I've adjusted the examples.